# Prove that in a field $F, \exists a,b,c \in F$ such that $x^3+x^2+1$ is a divisor of $x^{2018} + ax^3 + bx + c$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have no idea how to even start this! Maybe using the Euclidean algorithm and showing that the extra term is 0?

Comment: Yes, just try this way... More precisely, adjust $a$, $b$ and $c$ to obtain a rest equal to $0$.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Could you please explain a little more.  I have that by the Euclidean algorithm, there exist $f,r \in F[x]$ such that  $x^{2018} + ax^3 + bx + c$ = $(x^3+x^2+1)f(x) + r(x)$, where the degree of $r(x)$ is less than 2018, but I don't get how to manipulate $a,b,c$

Comment: The degree of $r(x)$ is $< 3$.

Comment: Oh right.  Thank you, but I still don't see how to manipulate $a,b,c$? I know that $f = x^{2015} + ...$ so we need something to get rid of the $x^{2016}, x^{2015}$ terms, but I don't see how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply Euclidean algorithm to $x^{2018}$ and $x^3+x^2+1$, we can find a polynomial $q(x)$ and quadratic polynomial $\alpha x^2 + \beta x + \gamma$ such that

$$x^{2018} = q(x)(x^3+x^2+1) + \alpha x^2 + \beta x + \gamma\\
\Downarrow\\
x^{2018} + ax^3 + bx + c = q(x)(x^3+x^2+1) + \underbrace{ax^3 + \alpha x^2 + (\beta+b)x + (\gamma + c)}_{\mathcal{M}}$$
If we take $a = \alpha, b = -\beta, c =\alpha - \gamma$, we have
$$\mathcal{M} = \alpha (x^3 + x^2 + 1)
\quad\implies\quad
x^{2018} + ax^3 + bx + c = (q(x)+\alpha)(x^3+x^2+1)$$
For such a choice of $a,b$ and $c$, $x^3+x^2+1$ is a factor of $x^{2018} + ax^3 + bx + c$.

Comment: This is perfect thank you!  It makes perfect sense, but how did you know that you should just take the $x^{2018}$ term for the Euclidean algorithm?

Comment: @JohnSmith Instead of $x^{2018}$, you can use any $x^{2018} + a_0 x^3 + b_0x + c_0$ for the Euclidean algorithm. Since there isn't other obvious choice one should use, I just pick the simplest one.